# Android Presenter Testing IllegalStateException captor.capture() must not be null

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito, android-mvp

I have simple application based on mvp. Write test for presenter. Used Mockito for mock data. I  catch view callback data (ArrayList) with ArgumentCaptor. My Test class

```
    @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)
    class MainPresenterTest{

    @Mock
    lateinit var view:MainView

    @Mock
    lateinit var context:Context

    @InjectMocks
    lateinit var presenter: MainPresenter

    @Captor
    lateinit var captor: ArgumentCaptor<ArrayList<News>>

    @Before
    fun init(){
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
    }

    @Test
    fun success(){
    presenter.loadNews()
    Mockito.verify<MainView>(view).onSuccess(captor.capture())
    var data =  captor.value
    Mockito.verify(view).onSuccess(data)
    Mockito.verify(view,never()).onError("")
        }
    }
```

Main View

```
interface MainView{
    fun onSuccess(n:ArrayList<News>)
    fun onError(e:String)
}
```

But throw

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: captor.capture() must not be null
Example of correct verification:
    verify(mock).doSomething()

Also, this error might show up because you verify either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.
Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need to define it as a class lateinit variable. In your test method, define a method variable like this

```
 @Test
    fun success(){
    presenter.loadNews()
    val captor: ArgumentCaptor<ArrayList<*>> = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(ArrayList::class.java)
    Mockito.verify<MainView>(view).onSuccess(captor.capture())
    var data =  captor.value
    Mockito.verify(view).onSuccess(data)
    Mockito.verify(view,never()).onError("")
        }
    }
```

Also, you should assert the data from the captor. Instead of this

```
 Mockito.verify(view).onSuccess(data)
```

do something like this

```
assertEquals("x", data.size())
```

Comment: ArgumentCaptor<ArrayList<*>> = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(ArrayList::class.java) wrong argument. required ArrayList<News> found ArrayList<*>

Comment: Then try not to specify the type like this

val captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(ArrayList::class.java)